# Is it possible to run ML models on SBC boards?

Tags: machine-learning

Can I run models like Tortoise TTS or OpenAI Whisper on SBCs like [Orange Pi 5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BLXWXSQQ) or [Odroid N2+](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WYRBJMX)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may be able to run some sizes of Whisper, depending on the available amount of RAM.

Specifically, you may be able to run Whisper tiny or base through [whisper.cpp](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp). [Here](https://github.com/ggerganov/whisper.cpp/issues/89#issuecomment-1318463033) you can find benchmarks with different model sizes on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 2Gb. It will probably not be very fast, though.